# Forced to refresh page after a facebook user grants permissions in order to continue

Tags: php, facebook, api, permissions

I needed to request permission to a facebook user to get specific informations (email,birthday).

When a user launches the application for the first time, if he accepts the permission, he is forced to refresh the page to display data (just informations concerning the user,see my code).

The problem is it works fine sometime,that's why i don't know if it is a facebook problem or a problem in my own code.

If you can have a look at my code, some help would be much appreciated!
thanks in advance

```
<?php
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '453976824647366',
            'secret' => 'fe86f3b0b34b3ed6XXXXXX',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            h1 a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #3b5998;
            }
            h1 a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday" size="large" onlogin="window.location = 'youlike.php';">Connect to this application using Facebook</fb:login-button>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
        <h3>Vous</h3>
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">


        <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
        Date de Naissance : <?php echo $user_profile["birthday"]; 


                echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="pic">';
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>'; 
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';?>
    <?php endif ?>
</body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</div>
<script>
    FB.init({appId: '453976824647366', status: true,
        cookie: true, xfbml: true});

</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always force a refresh on `login`/`logout`, just to be sure:

after your `FB.init`

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working. I still have to refresh the page to display the informations.I'd like to make clear this problems only occurs while the first log-in, it works properly if i disconnect and reconnect...no need to refresh anymore
Weird!